Generate the WebAPI Swagger API Json & Html documentation during build time
I'm working on an Asp.Net 4.8 WebAPI project and using Swashbuckle for API Documentation. I need to generate the WebAPI Swagger API Json & Html documentation during build time. I tried using a PowerShell script during the post-build process, but it requires starting the server using IISExpress to generate the JSON documentation.
I'm looking for a different approach using configuration settings to generate the JSON documentation instead of relying on IISExpress. Any suggestions or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
